# Oracle 10g : Unpivot Column Names and Values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table and the associated values.I need to Unpivot that table and take columns to rows with Column names.

In my scenario **GL_** Columns Dynamically grow.

### Create Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_NEWS
(
  NEWS_ID            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  STAFF_ID           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MODIFIED_USER      VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD  NUMBER(38),
  GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD  NUMBER(38)

)
```

### Insert Script

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NEWS (
NEWS_ID, STAFF_ID,
MODIFIED_USER,GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD,GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD) 
VALUES (1 ,100,System,50,40);
```

> Finally,My Result table needs to looks like this,Allways i need 1 users record

**COLUMN_NAME**                         **NEWSCOUNT**
GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD                                           50
GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD                                           40

I Tried to take that,By using following query i can take the Column Names.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TBL_NEWS' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GL_%')
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT in oracle 11g and use the below query to achieve your requirement in Oracle 10g or below:

```
select 'GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD' As COLUMN_NAME,GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD  as NEWSCOUNT
from TBL_NEWS
union all
select 'GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD' as COLUMN_NAME ,GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD as NEWSCOUNT
from TBL_NEWS
```

Or if you have oracle 11g and upper verison you can use:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,NEWSCOUNT
from TBL_NEWS
unpivot(  NEWSCOUNT
         for COLUMN_NAME  in (GL_NEWS_LOCAL_BRD ,GL_GRD_GLOBAL_BRD));
```